# Calculate Timestamp Difference Between Two Consecutive Rows in Oracle SQL (LAG() is giving null results)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this:

| TIMESTAMP | P_ID | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-JAN-19 09.54.48.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message1 |
| 11-JAN-19 09.54.58.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message2 |
| 11-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message3 |
| 15-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message4 |
| 16-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message5 |
| 16-JAN-19 10.00.09.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message6 |
| 16-JAN-19 11.30.09.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message7 |

and the output should be difference between two consecutive rows.

so, the required result is:

| TIMESTAMP | P_ID | Message | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-JAN-19 09.54.48.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message1 | 00:00:10 |
| 11-JAN-19 09.54.58.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message2 | 00:02:10 |
| 11-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message3 | 96:00:00 |
| 15-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message4 | 24:00:00 |
| 16-JAN-19 09.56.08.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message5 | 00:04:01 |
| 16-JAN-19 10.00.09.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message6 | 01:30:00 |
| 16-JAN-19 11.30.09.980000 AM +01:00 | bim_123 | message7 | 00:00:00 |

the difference represents difference between two consecutive messages "message1" and "message2".
There will be multiple p_ids and P_ID is a varchar() type, Message is also varchar() type and TIMESTAMP is TIMESTAMP type

Comment: What the problem you have? Please be more specific. Please post your query and some info what's not working. Keep in mind that based on your desired output - you should use `LEAD` instead of `LAG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function and then `EXTRACT` and `TO_CHAR` to format the difference:

```sql
SELECT timestamp,
       p_id,
       message,
       TO_CHAR(
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM difference) * 24
         + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM difference),
         'FM999900'
       )
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM difference), 'FM00')
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM difference), 'FM00') AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY timestamp)
           - timestamp AS difference
  FROM   table_name t
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (TIMESTAMP, P_ID, Message) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-11 09:54:48.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-11 09:54:58.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-11 09:56:08.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-15 09:56:08.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-16 09:56:08.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-16 10:00:09.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-01-16 11:30:09.980000 +01:00', 'bim_123', 'message7' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TIMESTAMP | P_ID | MESSAGE | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2019-01-11 09:54:48.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message1 | 00:00:10 |
> | 2019-01-11 09:54:58.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message2 | 00:01:10 |
> | 2019-01-11 09:56:08.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message3 | 96:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-15 09:56:08.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message4 | 24:00:00 |
> | 2019-01-16 09:56:08.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message5 | 00:04:01 |
> | 2019-01-16 10:00:09.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message6 | 01:30:00 |
> | 2019-01-16 11:30:09.980000000 +01:00 | bim_123 | message7 | 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b451648b0d70389b01af21e3e575ad1)*